# How to avoid the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions in this pgm?

Tags: android

How to avoid the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions.in the pgm myval and myvals is ArrayList Global Variables.i think i  covert the GlobalVariable , ArrayList to String[] is only the pbm.plz help me .

```
    public class TicketActivity extends Activity{
TextView t1;
TextView t2;
ListView l1;
TextView t6;
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.ticket);
  t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
  t2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
   l1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

     //Get the Table no Value From Edit Text


   Intent i1=getIntent();
   Bundle b=i1.getExtras();
    int num=b.getInt("Table No:");
    String pno=Integer.toString(num);
    t1.setText(pno);

        //Get The Guest Value From Edit Text

    Intent i2=getIntent();
    Bundle b1=i2.getExtras();
    int num1=b1.getInt("Guest:");
    String pno1=Integer.toString(num1);
    t2.setText(pno1);



    l1.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(TicketActivity.this));

   } 
   private static class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;



    public EfficientAdapter(Context context){
        mInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);

    // implementation of EfficientAdapter   
    }
    public int getCount() {

        return HomeActivity.select1.length;

    }
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return position;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position ;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        String[] stockArr = new String[GlobalClass.myval.size()];
        stockArr = GlobalClass.myval.toArray(stockArr);
        String[] stockArr1=new String[GlobalClass.myvals.size()];
        stockArr1=GlobalClass.myvals.toArray(stockArr1);
    if(convertView==null){
            convertView=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_ticket, null);
            holder=new ViewHolder();
            holder.Text1=(TextView)          convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.Text2=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            holder.Text3=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else{
              holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.Text2.setText(stockArr[position]);
            holder.Text3.setText(stockArr1[position]);
            return convertView;

     }

    }
    static class ViewHolder{
        TextView Text1;
        TextView Text2;
        TextView Text3;

    }
      }
```

LogCat output:

```
   08-03 10:50:59.417: I/dalvikvm(807): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    08-03 10:50:59.497: I/dalvikvm(807): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
   08-03 10:52:22.737: I/dalvikvm(807): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
   08-03 10:52:23.076: I/dalvikvm(807): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
   08-03 10:52:23.236: I/dalvikvm(807): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
   08-03 10:52:23.387: I/dalvikvm(807): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    08-03 10:52:23.507: W/System.err(807): java.lang.NullPointerException
    08-03 10:52:23.537: W/System.err(807):  at com.eConnect.Restaurant.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:142)
   08-03 10:52:23.537: W/System.err(807):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
   08-03 10:52:23.647: W/System.err(807):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
   08-03 10:52:23.647: W/System.err(807):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
   08-03 10:52:23.681: W/System.err(807):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
   08-03 10:52:23.696: W/System.err(807):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
   08-03 10:52:23.696: W/System.err(807):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
   08-03 10:52:23.728: W/System.err(807):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    08-03 10:52:23.736: W/System.err(807):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    08-03 10:52:23.776: W/System.err(807):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
    08-03 10:52:23.776: W/System.err(807):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    08-03 10:52:23.797: W/System.err(807):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    08-03 10:52:23.797: W/System.err(807):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    08-03 10:52:23.827: I/dalvikvm(807): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    08-03 10:52:24.107: I/dalvikvm(807): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    08-03 10:52:24.196: W/System.err(807):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
     08-03 10:52:24.196: W/System.err(807):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    08-03 10:52:24.257: I/dalvikvm(807): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    08-03 10:52:24.269: D/dalvikvm(807): GC_CONCURRENT freed 100K, 3% free 9379K/9607K, paused 11ms+9ms
    08-03 10:52:24.427: I/dalvikvm(807): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    08-03 10:52:24.790: I/dalvikvm(807): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    08-03 10:52:24.938: I/dalvikvm(807): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    08-03 10:52:25.267: I/dalvikvm(807): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    08-03 10:52:25.447: I/dalvikvm(807): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
     08-03 10:52:25.786: I/dalvikvm(807): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    08-03 10:52:25.939: I/dalvikvm(807): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    08-03 10:52:26.286: I/dalvikvm(807): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    08-03 10:52:26.477: I/dalvikvm(807): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    08-03 10:53:13.687: I/System.out(807): Length of Breakfast:12
     08-03 10:53:13.687: I/System.out(807): Length of P2:12
    08-03 10:53:15.837: I/System.out(807): Values[2EGG W/MEAT]
    08-03 10:53:15.837: I/System.out(807): Values[$ 4.7]
    08-03 10:53:17.248: I/System.out(807): Values[2EGG W/MEAT, BLUEBERRY CAKE]
    08-03 10:53:17.248: I/System.out(807): Values[$ 4.7, $ 3.0]
    08-03 10:53:21.317: I/dalvikvm(807): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    08-03 10:53:21.467: I/dalvikvm(807): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    08-03 10:53:21.817: I/dalvikvm(807): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    08-03 10:53:21.917: I/dalvikvm(807): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    08-03 10:53:22.087: D/AndroidRuntime(807): Shutting down VM
    08-03 10:53:22.087: W/dalvikvm(807): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
    08-03 10:53:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(807): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    08-03 10:53:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(807): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2
    08-03 10:53:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at com.eConnect.Restaurant.TicketActivity$EfficientAdapter.getView(TicketActivity.java:91)
     08-03 10:53:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(807):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2033)
     08-03 10:53:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(807):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1772)
     08-03 10:53:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(807):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
     08-03 10:53:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(807):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:732)
     08-03 10:53:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(807):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1625)
     08-03 10:53:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(807):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1863)
     08-03 10:53:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(807):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
     08-03 10:53:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(807):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
     08-03 10:53:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(807):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
      08-03 10:53:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(807):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1486)
      08-03 10:53:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(807):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
       08-03 10:53:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(807):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
     08-03 10:53:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(807):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
      08-03 10:53:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(807):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
      08-03 10:53:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(807):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
      08-03 10:53:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(807):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
      08-03 10:53:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(807):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
      08-03 10:53:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(807):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1486)
      08-03 10:53:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(807):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
      08-03 10:53:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(807):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
      08-03 10:53:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(807):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
      08-03 10:53:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(807):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
         08-03 10:53:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(807):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
      08-03 10:53:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(807):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
      08-03 10:53:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(807):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1489)
      08-03 10:53:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(807):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
      08-03 10:53:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(807):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
      08-03 10:53:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(807):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
       08-03 10:53:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(807):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
        08-03 10:53:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
         08-03 10:53:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(807):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
      08-03 10:53:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(807):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
      08-03 10:53:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(807):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
      08-03 10:53:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(807):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     08-03 10:53:22.358: I/dalvikvm(807): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
```

Thanks in Advance;

Comment: Can you post LogCat output, please?

Comment: in the HomeActivity.select1.length is smaller than

Comment: You should test that `position < GlobalClass.myvals.size()`

Comment: Also you unnecessarily create 2 arrays - why not use the list directly?

Comment: am already used Custom ListView and display the vaule in another Activity using two Column listView.so i am Created Two Arrays

Comment: @Cdr.Powell nw am updated logCat plz help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure, HomeActivity.select1.length, and GlobalClass.myval.size() and GlobalClass.myvals.size() are of same size.

I am editing your answer, please make a note its just a workaround, coz to get a proper solution I need to understand these data sources well.

```
public class TicketActivity extends Activity{
TextView t1;
TextView t2;
ListView l1;
TextView t6;
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.ticket);
  t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
  t2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
   l1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

     //Get the Table no Value From Edit Text


   Intent i1=getIntent();
   Bundle b=i1.getExtras();
    int num=b.getInt("Table No:");
    String pno=Integer.toString(num);
    t1.setText(pno);

        //Get The Guest Value From Edit Text

    Intent i2=getIntent();
    Bundle b1=i2.getExtras();
    int num1=b1.getInt("Guest:");
    String pno1=Integer.toString(num1);
    t2.setText(pno1);



    l1.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(TicketActivity.this));

   } 
   private static class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;



    public EfficientAdapter(Context context){
        mInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);

    // implementation of EfficientAdapter   
    }
    public int getCount() {

        return GlobalClass.myval.size()<GlobalClass.myvals.size()?GlobalClass.myval.size():GlobalClass.myvals.size();

    }
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return position;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position ;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        String[] stockArr = new String[GlobalClass.myval.size()];
        stockArr = GlobalClass.myval.toArray(stockArr);
        String[] stockArr1=new String[GlobalClass.myvals.size()];
        stockArr1=GlobalClass.myvals.toArray(stockArr1);
    if(convertView==null){
            convertView=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_ticket, null);
            holder=new ViewHolder();
            holder.Text1=(TextView)          convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.Text2=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            holder.Text3=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else{
              holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.Text2.setText(stockArr[position]);
            holder.Text3.setText(stockArr1[position]);
            return convertView;

     }

    }
    static class ViewHolder{
        TextView Text1;
        TextView Text2;
        TextView Text3;

    }
      }
```

Comment: no jeet i think HomeActivity.select1.length is smaller than others

Comment: its not case, I think any one among, GlobalClass.myval or GlobalClass.mycals is of size less then array HomeActivity.select1

Comment: so jeet plz help me .am new one in android

Comment: As far as I can see jeet is right. Did you try to output those values via Log.d() or checking the values via breakpoints to be sure thats not the case?